# Dynamic Context Menu options

Tags: android

Is it possible to create a dynamic context menu in android?

What I mean is, for example, if I have a list of items, that can be in two states: "read" and "unread". I want to be able to bring up a context menu with an option of "Mark as Read" for the unread items, and "Mark as Unread" for the read items.

So clicking on:

```
> read
> unread <-- click
> read
```

will show context menu "Mark as Read" resulting in:

```
> read
> read
> read   <-- click
```

will show the menu "Mark as Unread".

Is there some function that allows me to customize the creation of the context menu, just before it is displayed?

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you don't provide code, this is is the basic approach:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu contextMenu,
                                View v,
                                ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info =
            (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;

    String actionString = "Mark as Read";

    // if it's alredy read
    if ( ((TextView) info.targetView).getText().toString().equals("read") )
        actionString = "Mark as Unread";

    menu.setHeaderTitle("Action");
    menu.add(0, 0, 0, actionString);
}
```

In this case, I'm assuming the list is populated with `TextView`s that can have the string "read" or "unread" in it. As I already said, this is a very basic approach. The important thing here is to notice how the `ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo` object is being used.

Also, to read the state of the item that was selected you can use the `item.getMenuInfo()` method inside the `onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)` method.

Comment: What does the .targetView member represent? Thank you!

Comment: When you build a List on Android, each item in the list is a `View`. You can use different types of Views, for instance a simple `TextView` (as in the example above) or a custom view (for example, an external layout into an XML with a `LinearLayout`, different `TextView`s, Images, etc). The `targetView` represents the `View` your are using to display each item in the list.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do this is to create two separate menu items, "Mark as read" and "Mark as unread" and then hide one of them whenever the menu is displayed:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
                                ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    if (<is unread>)
        menu.findItem(R.id.mark_unread).setVisible(false);
    else
        menu.findItem(R.id.mark_read).setVisible(false);
}
```

Setting the text (and especially reading the text) directly from code is brittle; the text may change, and what if you want to support multiple languages?